# How to do a filter on a many to many relationship where one model does *not* include the other?

Tags: sql, database

My models look like this in a many-to-many relation 
I have setup up my linking table correctly. But i do not know how to

--> Get all `Film` that are **not** part of `Actor` x.

Do i need JOINS* to do this? or simple SELECT?
Any hint is much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The general way is to use `not exists`:

```
select f.*
from film f
where not exists (select 1 from actor_film_mapping where film_id = f.film_id);
```

However, the `JOIN` (i.e. `LEFT JOIN`) will also take a place with bit filtration such `IS NULL`

```
select f.*
from film f 
left join actor_film_mapping am on am.film_id = f.film_id
where am.film_id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use <>  (not equal) in WHERE Clause

```
SELECT * FROM actor_film_mapping WHERE actor_id <>  actor_x_ID;
```

this will show all films that are not part of Actor X

Comment: i am confused on this last part `actor_id <>  actor_x_ID;`  Can you let me know what  `<>` does?

Comment: @swiftnub Where `=` means `equal to`, `<>` means `not equal to`. Similar to `!=` in other languages (If you're using MySql, [it actually supports `!=`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal))